# ServiceStack AutoQuery - Table not accessibele

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, servicestack-autoquery

When I try to use the **IncludeTables** property, the table is not generated or is not accessible using the AutoQuery API. When calling /metadata I only see these two endpoints:

- CancelRequest
- GetFile

Is there a way to debug this or does someone know why the table is not picked up by AutoQuery?

***Edited***:
When I call https://localhost:5001/crud/tables I can see the product table as result ...

```cs
appHost.Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryFeature
    {
        MaxLimit = 1000,
        GenerateCrudServices = new GenerateCrudServices
        {
            AutoRegister = true,
            CreateServices = new List<CreateCrudServices>
            {
                new CreateCrudServices
                {
                    IncludeTables = new List<string> { "product"}
                },

            }
        }
    });
```

**Update:**

@mythz I've inspected the table schema, but did not find any errors (MySql). These are the columns:

```json
[
  {
     "ColumnName":"id",
     "ColumnOrdinal":1,
     "ColumnSize":16,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":true,
     "BaseColumnName":"id",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.Byte[]",
     "AllowDBNull":false,
     "ProviderType":754,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"BLOB",
     "ColumnDefinition":"BLOB(16) PRIMARY KEY"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"version_id",
     "ColumnOrdinal":2,
     "ColumnSize":16,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":true,
     "BaseColumnName":"version_id",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.Byte[]",
     "AllowDBNull":false,
     "ProviderType":754,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"BLOB",
     "ColumnDefinition":"BLOB(16) PRIMARY KEY"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"auto_increment",
     "ColumnOrdinal":3,
     "ColumnSize":11,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"auto_increment",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.Int32",
     "AllowDBNull":false,
     "ProviderType":3,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":true,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"INT",
     "ColumnDefinition":"INT NOT NULL"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"parent_id",
     "ColumnOrdinal":4,
     "ColumnSize":16,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"parent_id",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.Byte[]",
     "AllowDBNull":true,
     "ProviderType":754,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"BLOB",
     "ColumnDefinition":"BLOB(16) NULL"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"parent_version_id",
     "ColumnOrdinal":5,
     "ColumnSize":16,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"parent_version_id",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.Byte[]",
     "AllowDBNull":true,
     "ProviderType":754,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"BLOB",
     "ColumnDefinition":"BLOB(16) NULL"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"media_id",
     "ColumnOrdinal":6,
     "ColumnSize":16,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"media_id",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.Byte[]",
     "AllowDBNull":true,
     "ProviderType":754,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"BLOB",
     "ColumnDefinition":"BLOB(16) NULL"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"cms_page_id",
     "ColumnOrdinal":7,
     "ColumnSize":16,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"cms_page_id",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.Byte[]",
     "AllowDBNull":true,
     "ProviderType":754,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"BLOB",
     "ColumnDefinition":"BLOB(16) NULL"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"cms_page_version_id",
     "ColumnOrdinal":8,
     "ColumnSize":16,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"cms_page_version_id",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.Byte[]",
     "AllowDBNull":false,
     "ProviderType":754,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"BLOB",
     "ColumnDefinition":"BLOB(16) NOT NULL"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"product_stream_id",
     "ColumnOrdinal":9,
     "ColumnSize":16,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"product_stream_id",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.Byte[]",
     "AllowDBNull":true,
     "ProviderType":754,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"BLOB",
     "ColumnDefinition":"BLOB(16) NULL"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"product_assignment_type",
     "ColumnOrdinal":10,
     "ColumnSize":32,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"product_assignment_type",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.String",
     "AllowDBNull":false,
     "ProviderType":253,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"VARCHAR",
     "ColumnDefinition":"VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"path",
     "ColumnOrdinal":11,
     "ColumnSize":-1,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"path",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.String",
     "AllowDBNull":true,
     "ProviderType":752,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":true,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"VARCHAR",
     "ColumnDefinition":"VARCHAR NULL"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"after_category_id",
     "ColumnOrdinal":12,
     "ColumnSize":16,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"after_category_id",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.Byte[]",
     "AllowDBNull":true,
     "ProviderType":754,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"BLOB",
     "ColumnDefinition":"BLOB(16) NULL"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"after_category_version_id",
     "ColumnOrdinal":13,
     "ColumnSize":16,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"after_category_version_id",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.Byte[]",
     "AllowDBNull":true,
     "ProviderType":754,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"BLOB",
     "ColumnDefinition":"BLOB(16) NULL"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"level",
     "ColumnOrdinal":14,
     "ColumnSize":11,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"level",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.UInt32",
     "AllowDBNull":false,
     "ProviderType":503,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"INT",
     "ColumnDefinition":"INT NOT NULL"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"active",
     "ColumnOrdinal":15,
     "ColumnSize":1,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"active",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.Boolean",
     "AllowDBNull":false,
     "ProviderType":1,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"tinyint",
     "ColumnDefinition":"TINYINT(1) NOT NULL"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"child_count",
     "ColumnOrdinal":16,
     "ColumnSize":11,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"child_count",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.UInt32",
     "AllowDBNull":false,
     "ProviderType":503,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"INT",
     "ColumnDefinition":"INT NOT NULL"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"display_nested_products",
     "ColumnOrdinal":17,
     "ColumnSize":1,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"display_nested_products",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.Byte",
     "AllowDBNull":false,
     "ProviderType":501,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"INT",
     "ColumnDefinition":"INT NOT NULL"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"visible",
     "ColumnOrdinal":18,
     "ColumnSize":1,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"visible",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.Byte",
     "AllowDBNull":false,
     "ProviderType":501,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"INT",
     "ColumnDefinition":"INT NOT NULL"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"type",
     "ColumnOrdinal":19,
     "ColumnSize":32,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":0,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"type",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.String",
     "AllowDBNull":false,
     "ProviderType":253,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"VARCHAR",
     "ColumnDefinition":"VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"created_at",
     "ColumnOrdinal":20,
     "ColumnSize":23,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":3,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"created_at",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.DateTime",
     "AllowDBNull":false,
     "ProviderType":12,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"DATETIME",
     "ColumnDefinition":"DATETIME(23) NOT NULL"
  },
  {
     "ColumnName":"updated_at",
     "ColumnOrdinal":21,
     "ColumnSize":23,
     "NumericPrecision":0,
     "NumericScale":3,
     "IsUnique":false,
     "IsKey":false,
     "BaseColumnName":"updated_at",
     "BaseSchemaName":"shopware_6_demo",
     "BaseTableName":"category",
     "DataType":"System.DateTime",
     "AllowDBNull":true,
     "ProviderType":12,
     "IsAliased":false,
     "IsExpression":false,
     "IsAutoIncrement":false,
     "IsRowVersion":false,
     "IsHidden":false,
     "IsLong":false,
     "IsReadOnly":false,
     "DataTypeName":"DATETIME",
     "ColumnDefinition":"DATETIME(23) NULL"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you use `IncludeTables` the table selection becomes opt-in "white-list". The `CancelRequest` and `GetFile` are built-in APIs that are not relevant to AutoQuery.

You can test what Tables AutoQuery resolves by calling the static method, e.g:

```cs
var tableSchemas = GenerateCrudServices.GetTableSchemas(dbFactory, 
    includeTables:new List<string> { "product" });
```

If you leave of the off the `includeTables` filter, you can inspect the resulting table metadatas from the specified schema (or default if none is provided) where you can inspect the name from the RDBMS metadata with `tableSchemas[0].Name`.

Comment: Ii've updated my question. I did not find any errors and posted the columns definition.

Comment: @Nesse I'm assuming the issue is the blob PK again. Can you try with a table that doesn't have a binary PK?

Comment: I've tried a simple table also with a BINARY(16) PK, and this works. Could I be the complex table setup that shopware uses? multiple PK's, an auto_increment table, multiple references ...

Comment: @Nesse Yes a primary limitation for OrmLite, AutoQuery & essentially every data provider ServiceStack supports is that it only supports a [single primary key](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/limitations)

Comment: That explains my struggle :-). Is there a possibility that I exclude the second PK **version_id** column on my whole database?

Comment: So the generated result would be something link this [Ignore] VersionId ....

Comment: Yeah if you create the table manually, but AutoGen ignores tables with multiple PK's. I've just added `GenerateCrudServices.TableSchemasFilter` that will let you modify the DB Schema metadata that AutoGen uses, which you could use to change `Column.IsKey=false` on the PK you want to ignore. `TableSchemasFilter` is available from v6.1.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: wow, what a service. You're a lifesaver :-)

Comment: @Nesse that should get you to the next step where it's going to treat the table with a single PK, not sure how well that's going to work for your schema tho.  You should also be able to use this to change the binary PK to a `Guid` which should be able to work with a custom type converter.